# Measuring speed load test for website using multiple URLs w/ phantomjs

Tags: javascript, bash, raspberry-pi, phantomjs

I am newbie and just learned to use raspberry pi and phantomjs. Right now I'm using phantomjs to measure load speed test for website, so I want to know how to load multiple url(website) on the same time using bash script. Please help me, I appreciate and Thank you.

Here the original code that given by phantomjs.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    t = Date.now();
    address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } else {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log('Page title is ' + page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.title;
            }));
            console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

Comment: notice the `page.open(address, function (status) {` part? you could put the `function(status){..}` callback somewhere, and execute the `page.open` many times... but of course, you will need to populate the `t = Date.now()` for every test..

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the exact same thing you're attempting - I created a side-project to measure actual loading times. It uses Node and Nightmare (previously used PhantomJS under the hood, but now uses Electron) to manipulate a headless ("invisible") web browser. Once all of the resources are loaded, it reports the number of milliseconds it took to fully load the page.

One nice feature that would be useful for you is that it loads the webpage repeatedly. So, you could load the page multiple times and then average the values for a nice, round value. Also, since this script runs on the command-line, it's trivial to install on different machines and get actual loading times from various locations. (Load time depends not just on the server, but also the client and intermediaries)

Example usage:

```
website-loading-time rinogo$ node website-loading-time.js https://google.com
1657
967
1179
1005
1084
1076
...
```

https://github.com/rinogo/website-loading-time

Disclosure: I am the author of this project.